# How to get all <li> elements from html with C#

Tags: c#, html, html-lists

I have html code, which looks like that:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>title</h2>
<ul>
   <li> element </li>
   <li> element </li>
   <li> element </li>
...
</ul>

<h2>title 2</h2>
<ul>
   <li> element </li>
   <li> element </li>
   <li> element </li>
...
</ul>

etc.
```

My question is: how can i get all < li> elements into a List? I don't need titles, i just want elements from lists. 
I think HTML Agility Pack could be a solution, but i have no idea how to do that. Thanks for help!

Comment: I think, you should try yourself first

Comment: `"I think HTML Agility Pack could be a solution"` - That's exactly what I would suggest as well.  What happens when you try?  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: All right, i've done it. It was very simple. I was doing it in a bad way ;) Thanks for help.